# the setup failed to read IIsMimeMap table. The error code is -2147023550

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm trying to uninstall SQL Server from my machine so that I can install SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition.

I'm getting the following error message.

> the setup failed to read IIsMimeMap
>   table. The error code is -2147023550

Thank in advance.

Comment: In hex it's  80070542. Usually hex error codes are easier to google.

Comment: In this case that's the error displayed when the failure occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to stop IIS

```
c:> NET STOP "World Wide Web Publishing Service"
```

Answer (score 1):

Stopping IIS/IIS Admin didn't help me, nor did searching for the error code. However, [Microsoft has a solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910544). From the KB article:

Cause

> This issue occurs because the uninstall program cannot run correctly
>   if the virtual directories for SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services are
>   not present.

Workaround

> To work around this issue, re-create the virtual directories for SQL
>   Server 2005 Reporting Services by using the Reporting Services
>   Configuration tool. After you re-create the virtual directories, you
>   can uninstall or repair the installation of SQL Server 2005 Reporting
>   Services successfully.

I had a bad Website in IIS. I removed it, used the tool to recreate both of the required Virtual Directories, and then uninstalled successfully.